# Add loading before jquery function loaded completely

Tags: jquery, function, loading

I use the slick slider in my WordPress template and I have some problem with loading the items, I want to hide all item until the plugin loaded completely with a loading icon

Here's my jquery function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    rtl: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the items are loading before the jquery?

Comment: @Qudus Yes, they're messed up until jquery function load completely

Comment: Do you want to load the page completely (whole images & contents) before triggering slick?

Comment: @Thirumaniguhan I made a short video of the problem, please watch:https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1I5Mm37MhmYua7F0xmu02Kp5czTGc6NRA

Comment: @Thirumaniguhan Do you see that?

Comment: Yes, i added the answer

Comment: @Thirumaniguhan Where?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can add CSS to hide `visibility: hidden` the slick slider till it loaded completely. Slick will add the class `slick-initialized` once its loaded. so add CSS to show.
CSS Code will look like below,

```
.slider { visibility: hidden; }
.slider.slick-initialized { visibility: visible; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a script inside `document.ready` waits for the html page to load before running the script. Make a straightforward call instead.
Place the script at the top of your html page just to be sure.

```
<script>
    $('.slider').slick({
    rtl: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @MehranPourjenabi Is this html page where you have the jquery inheriting from another HTML layout/template in the application?

Comment: No, this is not the case